# How to handle event while clicking H/W OK button on android device

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a device having keypad(Hardware) attached on phone device.Now I want to get the event after clicking OK button on keypad.
i found we use DPAD_CENTER for specifiying OK Button.
Can anyone helps me on this. How set listener for this OK button. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override onkeydown function and you can do actions for whichever hardware key is pressed

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                // Do what you have to do here
            }
            return false;
        }
```